# Visual Studio not detecting Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2022

I have checked out an existing WinForms using SDK-Style csproj file, and Visual Studio does not detect the forms as forms that can be designed. As such, the WinForms designer cannot be used.

I can also reproduce this issue by creating a new net6 WinForms project and then deleting the csproj.user file containing information about the SubType. After reading about similar bugs in previous Visual Studio versions, the forms should be automatically detected and added to csproj.user file. However, this does not appear to happen for me.

Visual Studio version: 17.4.4

csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue you reported. You will have to report to Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022 and maybe contact their customer support directly if your company has support contracts.

Comment: Could you please share the code in your .csproj file?

Comment: I added the csproj content. It is the default one generated by the net6 WinForms template. It then only contains the default Form1.cs. Removing and re-adding the files through Visual Studio did not make it detect them as forms either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further testing and contact with Visual Studio support, I figured out that the issue is related to the "Run code analysis in separate process" setting. If this setting is disabled, Visual Studio does not detect the forms on its own. After enabling it, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run code analysis once, manually.

This can be done through the "Analysis" menu in VS. For me it fixed the situation where a set of forms was not recognized as such and did the forms did not open in designer view (double click gave me code view instead).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-run-code-analysis-manually-for-managed-code?view=vs-2022